# mouseOver in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart. There is no mouseOver event in chart options, but I need to get mouse coordinates when I move cursor. For example, I want to show coordinates on xAxis and yAxis. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can catch mousevent on the div which contain highcharts.

http://jsfiddle.net/5KHaj/2/

```
$('#highcharts-0').mouseover(function(e){
        $('#report').html(e.clientX + ' ' + e.clientY);

        });
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I need.

Comment: chart: {
         events: {
             click: function(event) {
                 alert (
                  'x: '+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', event.xAxis[0].value) +', ' +
                  'y: '+ event.yAxis[0].value
                 );
             }
         }
     }

for example this code alert X and Y values. I need the same, but on mouseover event

Comment: You can use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.events.mouseOver but on label's xAxis/yAxis you cannot achive value.

Answer (score 1):

Get the normal mouse coordinates then calculate the relative position.

```
document.body.onmousemove = function (event) {
    var x = event.target.x - <your_chart_element>.getBoundingClientRect().left
    var y = event.target.y - <your_chart_element>.getBoundingClientRect().top
}
```

Comment: I use dynamic chart with datetime in X and float values in Y. That's why I don't need real coordinates.